# С помощью чего лучше создать графический вывод бинарного файла(C++, QT)?

Tags: c++, qt

Изначально есть бинарный файл. Мне полностью известна его структура.

Хотелось бы его как-то графически нарисовать. Но дело в том, что список состоит из множества элементов(около 1000). Со связями друг с другом. Файл большой целиком в память не поместится.

Как можно реализовать отображение так, чтобы можно было открывать/закрывать элементы по связям, перемещать их итд?

Comment: Model view controller?

Comment: TableView, TreeView, ListView. Если стрктуру файла можно представить в виде дерева - TreeView. Данные подгружать динамически

Comment: MVC метод а не объект QT.

Comment: Table и прочее не подойдут изначально файл описывает 3д объекты. Если в 2д их ещё можно разместить нормально, то в 1д списке это не получится.

Comment: ну так напишите подробнее какая структура данных в файле и что надо выводить. в qt можно хоть в 3д рисовать.

Comment: Тут дело не в структуре а в элементах. Их надо отображать с перемещением и открытием ссылок.  Нужна графическая часть. Я конечно могу рисовать квадратики на холсте но хотелось бы воспользоваться возможностями QT.